# Trouble making an executable as a service

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I would like this to run as a service on my Ubuntu server 18.x...
https://github.com/xiaodoudou/PlexIPTV

I have downloaded the linux x64 file, made it executable in my home folder and tried to run it. I also setup the initial settings.json file in the same folder. It worked out fine, so to get it as a service I tried following this guide:
[How can I make an executable run as a service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478999/how-can-i-make-an-executable-run-as-a-service)

So I made the file in `/etc/systemd/system/`, looking like the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Plex IPTV-Tuner
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=plex
Group=plex
UMask=007

ExecStart=/usr/bin/PlexIPTV/PlexIPTV.linux-x64

Restart=on-failure

# Configures the time to wait before service is stopped forcefully.
TimeoutStopSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also moved the executable well as the `settings.json` file to `/usr/bin/PlexIPTV/`

Now, when I try to run the folder I get the error that it's not allowed to open `/settings.json`.
I've tried to `chmod 777 -R /usr/bin/PlexIPTV/` as well as `chown plex:plex -R /usr/bin/PlexIPTV` but it do not help.

Exact error I get:

```
● plex-iptv-tuner.service - Plex IPTV-Tuner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/plex-iptv-tuner.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2019-03-10 13:09:02 CET; 1s ago
  Process: 16218 ExecStart=/usr/bin/PlexIPTV/PlexIPTV.linux-x64 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16218 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 10 13:09:02 media systemd[1]: Started Plex IPTV-Tuner.
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]: 2019-03-10T12:09:02.397Z plexiptv:config:verbose 2019/03/10 13:09:02.3960  init Getting settings...
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]: 2019-03-10T12:09:02.398Z plexiptv:config:verbose 2019/03/10 13:09:02.3970  readSettings Reading file...
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]: 2019-03-10T12:09:02.399Z plexiptv:config:verbose 2019/03/10 13:09:02.3990  __dirname.readSettings.fs.readFile Didn't found file, injecting template...
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]: 2019-03-10T12:09:02.410Z plexiptv:config:error 2019/03/10 13:09:02.4090  __dirname.init.Q.fcall.then.then.catch.error Error happen during setting pulling:
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]: [ { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/settings.json'
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]:     errno: -13,
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]:     code: 'EACCES',
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]:     syscall: 'open',
Mar 10 13:09:02 media PlexIPTV.linux-x64[16218]:     path: '/settings.json' } ]
```

Comment: Do you actually get a "permission denied" error, or do you get "file not found"?  I'm asking because I see no reason for it to look for `settings.json` in the root (`/`) directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda added the full error.

Comment: _"I've tried to `chmod 777 -R /usr/bin/PlexIPTV/` ..."_ - NEVER do that; it gives every user and every process on your system write access to that directory, which can easily turn a smaller security problem into a much bigger one.

Comment: @marcelm yeah I know, I was just running mad when it kept saying that it did not have the permission.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I also setup the initial settings.json file in the same folder. It worked out fine, so to get it as a service...

In the systemd service, set `WorkingDirectory`.

Comment: Setting the `PLEXIPTV_SETTINGS` environment variable and using the `--settings` command-line option are alternatives.