# Creating a systemd service in ubuntu that can be started/stopped

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, executable

I have build a server that ships in executable format, and I want to register it as a service that I can start/stop/restart.

I have read the following questions and many others like it > [How can I make an executable run as a service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478999/how-can-i-make-an-executable-run-as-a-service)

My issue issue is that I want the executable process to be stopped by systemctl if I run `sudo systemctl stop myexecutableservice`.

In my current case if I stop the service, the background process is still running and my server is still accepting requests.

Comment: Any journal entries for when it is supposed to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer for the simplest case.

All you need to do is create `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`.  This is an INI file with a `[Service]` section.

A very simple service looks like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myapp arg1 arg2
```

Simply ensure this service exists, then `sudo systemctl start myservice` or `sudo systemctl stop myservice`.

There are lots of other things you can do in the `Service` section such as defining user, working directory, environment variables, how to manage forking processes, how to stop the process, priority, etc.  See  [`systemd.service(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#) for details of how this section works.

You can also add a `[Unit]` section which can be used to define a `Description=` that will appear in logs, and can define relationships to other units.  See  [`systemd.unit(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#).

An `[Install]` section can also be declared.  That will let you define what happens when `systemctl enable myservice` is used.  See  [`systemd.unit(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#).

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you point out at why my server started with this process does not get stopped on `stop` command?

Comment: There are a million reasons for this.  I suggest to ask a new question, giving your *.service file, and the output of `sudo systemctl status myservice`.

Comment: Otherwise this question is similar to "How do I program in C?" followed by "but my program doesn't work".

Comment: I deleted the old .service file, uploaded a new binary and it now it works

Comment: If you've made changes to the service file, those changes may not be immediately read by systemd.  `systemctl daemon-reload` is needed for force systemd to re-read the unit files.  That could have been the problem.  Otherwise, it could have been the binary.

Comment: my executable was starting another process and I forgot to kill it in all application exit scenarios, hence why some services were still running

Answer (score 0):

My executable started another process that was not killed in every exit event, so I created a new .service file and recompiled by executable. It now works perfectly.